# How to run Shortcuts through Siri?

Tags: ios, siri, shortcuts-app

I’ve been using Shortcuts for a while and knew how to run Shortcuts with Siri, but since iOS 13, I couldn’t find the option.

Comment: What do you mean by "option"?  What are you trying to do?  Have you looked in the Shortcuts app?

Comment: @fsb I’m trying to activate a shortcut through Siri (i.e. if the run phrase was “hello word”, I could say “Hey Siri, hello world” to run the shortcut). I’ve looked through the app but haven’t found anything.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 13, Apple moved the "Siri Shortcuts" into the Shortcuts app.  Open the Shortcuts app and select "Gallery".

In there you'll see "Shortcuts From your Apps".  Tap "See All" to see all Shortcuts that you can use with Siri.

[image]

Comment: I meant the voice activation, as my comment says

Comment: Yes, this is where you setup the voice commands for Siri to use, as the Answer indicates..  This page used to be in Settings in previous iOS versions.  It’s all consolidated in the Shortcuts app.  Did you go to the screen and try adding a Shortcut to trigger with Siri?  The screenshot shows “Great Shortcuts for Siri.  Add these shortcuts to Siri to get things done with your voice.”

Comment: That’s just a bunch of shortcuts that work with Siri

Comment: When I go to that part, I can record shortcuts that I want activated or triggered when I speak to Siri.  That’s exactly what your question is asking how to do.  If it’s not, I recommend editing your question to add more detail.